# How to attach multiple managed policies to a group using AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I want to attach **multiple managed policies** to a group, but, looking at the documentation `attach-group-policy` parameter/flag `--policy-arn` receives just a string.

Does anyone know how to attach multiple policies without creating a bash script that loops through each element on a list and executes the command nor creating a policy that contains the managed ones? Just using the cli.

Examples:
* arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEC2FullAccess
* arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonECS_FullAccess
* arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonESFullAccess

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this with a single CLI command. You would have to call `attach-group-policy` for each individual policy you want to attach. Here's what a script could look like

```
for arn in $policy_arns
do
    aws iam attach-group-policy \
            --policy-arn $arn \
            --group-name $group_name
done
```